# Horizontal line representing row vector in matrix

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I would like to produce a graphical representation of a matrix as stack of row vectors. Because I will be publishing the math on a website, I have access to the amsmath package but no others. I find that I can produce a representation of a matrix as a stack of column vectors using the following code

```
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc} 
\vline & \vline & \vline \\
\vline & \vline & \vline \\
\vline & \vline & \vline \\
\end{array}
\right)
```

What I would like is a transpose of this.

This question is similar to [How do I typeset vertical and horizontal lines inside a matrix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12910/how-do-i-typeset-vertical-and-horizontal-lines-inside-a-matrix) and [Long dashes for denoting omitted columns of a matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57411/long-dashes-for-denoting-omitted-columns-of-a-matrix), but when I apply the approaches found in those posts, I do not obtain a continuous horizontal line.

Comment: Not great, but try `\left(\begin{array}{ccc}  &  &  \\ \hline  &  &  \\ \hline  &  &  \\ \hline  & & \end{array} \right)`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Just use one column and say `\rule[2.2pt]{4em}{0.4pt}` in each row. Here 4em is the width, adjust to suit.

Comment: In essence, what @egreg says is the same as what the [accepted answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12914) to the first linked question proposes. Can you say more precisely what your problems with this approach are?

Comment: @egreg Thanks! That would seem to do the trick.

Comment: @Hendrik Yes, I agree now. I think I didn't understand the answer well enough at the time I posted.

Comment: @dsmith: Very understandable `:-)` it's not that easy to see what those arguments of `\rule` are used for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Saying simply `\vline` is not the best method, in my opinion. Try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\begin{pmatrix}
\kern.6em\vline & \kern.2em\vline\kern.2em & \vline\kern.6em \\
\kern.6em\vline & \kern.2em\vline\kern.2em & \vline\kern.6em \\
\kern.6em\vline & \kern.2em\vline\kern.2em & \vline\kern.6em \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\rule[.5ex]{3.5em}{0.4pt}\\
\rule[.5ex]{3.5em}{0.4pt}\\
\rule[.5ex]{3.5em}{0.4pt}
\end{pmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a mild mockup of two different approaches that doesn't require [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). The second requires [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) though. It duplicates your existing column representation, just horizontally:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\begin{document}
\[
  \left(
  \begin{array}{ccc} 
    \vline & \vline & \vline \\
    \vline & \vline & \vline \\
    \vline & \vline & \vline
  \end{array}
  \right) \quad
  \left(
  \begin{array}{p{3em}} 
    \raisebox{.5ex}{\rule{3em}{.4pt}} \\[\dimexpr-2\normalbaselineskip+2\tabcolsep]
    \raisebox{.5ex}{\rule{3em}{.4pt}} \\[\dimexpr-2\normalbaselineskip+2\tabcolsep]
    \raisebox{.5ex}{\rule{3em}{.4pt}}
  \end{array}
  \right)
\]
\[
  \left(
  \begin{array}{ccc} 
    \vline & \vline & \vline \\
    \vline & \vline & \vline \\
    \vline & \vline & \vline
  \end{array}
  \right) \quad
  \left(
  \begin{array}{c} 
    \rotatebox{90}{$
      \begin{array}{ccc} 
        \vline & \vline & \vline \\
        \vline & \vline & \vline \\
        \vline & \vline & \vline
    \end{array}$}
  \end{array}
  \right)
\]
\end{document}
```