# How to make this matrix in LaTeX?

Tags: pdftex, matrices

Ok, so I am trying to find a way to make this matrix shown here, in LaTeX:

[image]

I tried to search for this type, but I frankly do not know what one would call this, so I had to draw a picture shown here to illustrate what I mean. So basically, I want a matrix, but I need to make lines as rows as shown here, with the respective $$x_i^T$$ shown as well.

Would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Hello! I had this question a little while ago: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57411/10679. Hope this helps!

Comment: @kan Never mind it works! Question - how to change to make it vertical lines? Thanks!!

Comment: Oh, I think the code in question shows how there is an easy code for vertical lines using `\bigg|`. There is no such easy solution for the horizontal lines, which motivated the question.

Comment: @kan Thanks again! I have a second part to this question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108012/how-to-make-a-full-equation-with-tikz).