# General matrices

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I want to use LaTeX to add matrix that looks like this:

```
-----L_1-----

-----L_2-----

. . . . . . .

----L_n-----
```

and matrices where I want to show how a general cell in the matrix looks like (for example writing a matrix and then marking that 3 belongs to the i'th row and j'th column) , like here :

[image]

(I am not looking to a way to add the vertical lines ,but I want to have a matrix  filled with dots, except at the i,j place and there write $2^{i+j}$ [ I want a matrix that each cell has the value of 2^{row number +column number})

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm pretty sure there's already something like this on the site.

Comment: Thanks :)
I am pretty new here , and I didn't know how to explain what I need ... can you help me find this?

Comment: Perhaps http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57411/long-dashes-for-denoting-omitted-columns-of-a-matrix is what you want for the first problem

Comment: And http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196258/draw-a-vertical-line-over-the-entries-of-a-column-in-an-array for the second problem.

Comment: @egreg
for the first question : can I add dots( I want to say that the matrix has n rows)
For the second question : It is not exactly what I meant , I wanted to have a matrix , filled with dots, except at the i,j place and there write $2^{i+j}$ [ I want a matrix that each cell has the value of 2^{row number +column number}

Comment: There's `\hdotsfor` in the `amsmath` package. I'll add to my answer for the first problem.

Comment: Please, modify your question to reflect your last comment.

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem, look at [Long dashes for denoting omitted columns of a matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57411/long-dashes-for-denoting-omitted-columns-of-a-matrix)

For the second problem, the result will not be pretty:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pmatrix}
\makebox[9em]{\dotfill} \\
\makebox[9em]{\dotfill} \\
\makebox[9em]{\dotfill\ $2^{i+j}$ \dotfill} \\
\makebox[9em]{\dotfill} \\
\makebox[9em]{\dotfill} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

I'd very much prefer a simpler description:

> ```
> The matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ where $a_{ij}=2^{i+j}$, for $1\le i,j\le n$
> ```

[image]