# Typeset Kampé de Fériet function

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to reproduce the way the [Kampé de Fériet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamp%C3%A9_de_F%C3%A9riet_function) is typeset in a paper. Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Here's what I've got:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amstext, amsmath, amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\longdash}[1][2em]{%
  \makebox[#1]{$\m@th\smash-\mkern-7mu\cleaders\hbox{$\mkern-2mu\smash-\mkern-2mu$}\hfill\mkern-7mu\smash-$}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\omitskip}{\kern-\arraycolsep}
\newcommand{\llongdash}[1][2em]{\longdash[#1]\omitskip}
\newcommand{\rlongdash}[1][2em]{\omitskip\longdash[#1]}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
F_{2:0:0}^{0:2:1}\left[{\llongdash :\dfrac{a+b+1}{2},\dfrac{a-b+1}{2};1\atop \dfrac{a+b+3}{2},\dfrac{a-b+3}{2}:\llongdash;\rlongdash}\Bigg\vert x\dfrac{y^2}{4},\dfrac{y^2}{4}\right]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

which produces this:
[image]

It's close but not quite. The subscript and subperscript appear to be slightly shifted horizontally. Worse yet, the parameters (or arguments of the function) appear to be misaligned as well. Any advise?

The long dashes were borrowed from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57411/long-dashes-for-denoting-omitted-columns-of-a-matrix).

Comment: For your first problem a thinspace (`\,`)  can do the job. For the next problems I would suggest an `array` (Search for this)

Comment: About the superscripts and subscripts, you can add a italic correction (`\/`) after the F: `F\/_{2:0:0}^{0:2:1}`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use an array. You get staggered subscript and superscript by setting them to an empty subformula.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\linefill}{% a variation on \rightarrowfill
  {-}\mkern-7mu
  \cleaders\hbox{$\mkern-2mu-\mkern-2mu$}\hfill
  \mkern-7mu{-}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
F{}_{2:0:0}^{0:2:1}
  \left[
   \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}% local assignment
   \begin{array}{c@{{}:{}}c@{;{}}c}
   \linefill & \dfrac{a+b+1}{2},\dfrac{a-b+1}{2} & \quad 1 \\[1ex]
   \dfrac{a+b+3}{2},\dfrac{a-b+3}{2} & \qquad\linefill & \linefill
   \end{array}
   \;\middle|\;
   x\dfrac{y^2}{4},\dfrac{y^2}{4}
 \right]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Mixed use of `array`s, `\dfrac`s and `\phantom`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  F \mathstrut_{2:0;0}^{0:2;1}
    \left[
      \begin{array}{@{} c @{:} c @{;} c @{;}}
        \dfrac{\phantom{\mu + \nu + 3, \mu - \nu + 3}}{\phantom{2}} & 
          \dfrac{\mu + \nu + 1}{2}, \dfrac{\mu - \nu + 1}{2} &
          1 \\
        \dfrac{\mu + \nu + 3}{2}, \dfrac{\mu - \nu + 3}{2} &
          \dfrac{\phantom{\mu + \nu + 1, \mu - \nu + 1}}{\phantom{2}} &
          \dfrac{\phantom{0}}{\phantom{0}}
      \end{array}
      a \dfrac{z^2}{4}, \dfrac{z^2}{4}
    \right]
\]

\end{document}
```